# AngularJS ng-options not working with integers as key

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular form I'm having trouble with ng-options that have a key that is an integer as the value for the `<option>`

```
{{ form.status }} returns a string: 'foobar'

<select ng-model="form.status"
        ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in status_list">
```

key is a string > selected value is correct

```
{{ form.weekday }} returns an integer: 5

<select ng-model="form.weekday"
        ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in weekdays">
```

key is an integer > nothing is selected

Both are identical in code. Only the Json lists are different, weekdays are having an integer as key - the other a string. Why isn't it working with integers?

Comment: can you ensure form.weekday is 5 instead of '5'? They render the same.

Comment: Hmm, nope. If I change form.weekday the {{ form.weekday | json }} returns a string instead of integer. How to fix this? Then indeed it's correct they're not the same.

Comment: In the appropriate side (i.e. the end of the appropriate controller) do: `$scope.form.weekday = parseInt($scope.form.weekday)` at the end.

Comment: There are other things like form parsers and formatters but cannot remember right now how to use them. You should search in the documentation appropriately since I don't have any source code at hand.

Comment: For now, stick to the ugly solution: add the code I told you to the end. When using appropriately parsers and formatters, you will not need the additional code line I told you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select ng-init="form.weekday = form.weekday.toString()"
        ng-model="form.weekday"
        ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in weekdays">
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/wqbas2bp/

Html

```
<select ng-model="form.status"
ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in status_list"></select>

<select ng-model="form.status1"
ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in status_list"></select>
```

Javascript

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {    
$scope.status_list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
$scope.status_list1 = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" ];}
```

Both of the arrays seem to be working.

Comment: Your Fiddle refers both to the same list. But that's not the point. What the problem is, is that my option keys are seen as string; not integers.